# Merge large pickle files and save as dta

Tags: pandas, pickle, stata

I want to merge several large pickle files (around 500mb compression=gzip) and save it as dta file. I am using following code

```
df10= pd.read_pickle("10.pickle.gzip",compression="gzip")
df11= pd.read_pickle("11.pickle.gzip",compression="gzip")
new_df=pd.concat([df10,df11], ignore_index=True)

for col in new_df.columns:
     new_df[col] = new_df[col].astype(str)
        
new_df.to_stata("myfile.dta",version=119)
```

The script is killed for zsh when I am it tries to save it.

I want to merge several of such files and save it as dta then read it in Stata. Any advice on how to do it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get exactly?

Comment: I assume you're trying to append your datasets (row-wise and not column-wise). Have you tried `pd.append` instead of `pd.concat` ?